# What format is this list of times, lats and lons?

Tags: line, encoding, format, flash-builder

I have a bunch of strings from an XML file of a sailboat race (the Volvo Ocean Race 2011-2012). The XML file was consumed by an old flash app which I no longer have access to. I am 90% sure the positions of the boats, along with their times are encoded in strings that look like this:

```
<track id="20">3832917,-49133,1320498000;1600,3117,600;-184,3650,900;-166,-4167,900;-7784,-1750,900;-7866,-1434,900;-7584,-2217,900;-7999,-2183,900;-7417,-2317,900;-8050,-3200,900;-7800,-2683,900;-7250,-2450,900;-7200,-2900,900;-4850,-3500,900;-3667,-5017,900;-3583,-5100,900;-3850,-4883,900;-3667,-5450,900;-3967,-4683,900;-3716,-4450,900;-3700,-4817,900;-3784,-5050,900;-3866,-4967,900;-3350,-5133,900;-3050,-5183,900;-2834,-3967,900;-866,-250,900;-284,700,900;-266,750,900;-200,900,900;-400,967,900;-450,917,900;-800,2317,900;650,2900,900;1400,2350,900;2150,1950,900;2300,1850,900;2233,1983,900;2317,2133,900;2300,2383,900;2299,2417,900;2201,2383,900;2233,2400,900;2233,2350,900;2250,2450,900;2400,2400,900;2434,2433,900;2433,2583,900;2300,2783,900;2217,2834,900;2283,2483,900;2267,2117,900;2150,2117,900;1800,2750,900;1950,2750,900;2467,2467,900;2583,967,900;2366,967,900;2284,1017,900;2467,817,900;2549,1133,900;2634,367,900;2650,167,900;2650,-50,900;2650,17,900;2650,0,900;2750,-117,900;2833,1500,900;2733,1450,900;2700,1450,900;2867,1350,900;2850,1217,900;2817,1133,900;2700,1250,900;2866,1067,900;2917,1083,900;2550,2200,900;2683,800,900;2600,-167,900;2634,-83,900;2850,0,900;2850,-50,900;600,850,900;0,0,900;16,0,900;-16,0,7200;-34,0,900;17,-16,2700;-17,16,900;0,0,3600;34,0,900;-34,0,900;34,0,900;-34,0,900;0,-17,900;0,17,900;34,-16,900;0,16,1800;-34,0,900;17,-16,8100;-17,16,900;17,-16,9900;-17,16,900;17,-16,9900;-17,16,900;17,-16,9900;-17,16,900;17,-16,9900;-17,16,900;0,0,8100;17,-16,900;-17,16,10800;17,-16,900;0,0,10800;-17,16,900;0,0,9000;17,-16,900;0,0,10800;-17,16,900;0,0,9000;17,-16,900;-17,16,9900;17,-16,900;0,0,10800;-17,16,900;0,0,9000;17,-16,900;-17,16,9900;17,-16,900;0,0,10800;-17,16,900;17,-16,9900;-17,16,900;17,-16,9900;-17,16,900;17,-16,9900;-17,16,900;0,0,9000;17,-16,900;0,0,10800;-17,16,900;0,0,9000;17,-16,900;-17,16,9000;34,0,900;16,0,900;-16,0,900;16,0,9900;-16,0,900;0,0,1800;-900,-1100,900;-2050,-300,900;-2600,1950,900;-3017,-400,900;-3433,800,900;-3384,-1100,900;-1916,-4117,900;-4800,633,900;-4584,983,900;-4967,850,900;-5149,-150,900;-5350,-650,900;-5250,-1000,900;-4734,-867,900;-4383,-1033,900;-4483,-1750,900;-4100,-1700,900;-4800,-1150,900;-5000,-300,900;-4750,-650,900;-4750,-883,900;-4600,-767,900;-4450,-33,900;-4567,117,900;-4600,-167,900;-3883,-617,900;-100,-5350,900;-467,-5350,900;-984,-5300,900;-1383,-5183,900;-1149,-5267,900;-151,-5850,900;-216,-5733,900;-134,-5683,900;-766,-5600,900;-1367,-5250,900;-833,-5433,900;-951,-5050,900;-999,-5183,900;-1000,-5217,900;-967,-4850,900;-300,-5150,900;1267,-4550,900;-2717,-3450,900;-3083,-3667,900;-2350,-2850,900;-2984,-317,900;-3616,917,900;-3084,617,900;-3516,517,900;-3234,750,900;-3416,767,900;-3900,467,900;-3800,550,900;-2234,-617,900;84,-4050,900;-2050,567,900;-2684,1117,900;-2816,1250,900;-2601,2233,900;-2499,2717,900;-1150,-2567,900;-434,-4300,900;-266,-3600,900;-150,-3100,900;200,-2600,900;600,-3283,900;850,-4300,900;-500,-4350,900;-667,-4733,900;-667,-4833,900;717,-4750,900;-833,-5950,900;-150,-5950,900;500,-4783,900;-1767,-717,900;-4433,767,900;-3917,783,900;-2400,1700,900;-183,-2017,900;-400,-3050,900;-550,-3534,900;-400,-3917,900;50,-3883,900;750,-3700,900;1450,-4100,900;1016,-3983,900;967,-3817,900;567,-3900,900;483,-4300,900;867,-3800,900;1550,-3300,900;-1800,-1083,900;-2550,-417,900;-2450,100,900;-2300,300,900;-1734,633,900;-1116,1233,900;-1100,900,900;-350,467,900;-134,300,900;-166,267,900;-150,350,900;-150,400,900;-100,367,900;-1084,633,900;-1666,-183,900;-1600,583,900;-967,83,900;-183,-3033,900;600,-3350,900;550,-1950,900;-2717,133,900;-3367,67,900;600,-3350,900;734,-3250,900;450,-4017,900;-434,-4383,900;-200,-4550,900;-633,-4467,900;-183,-4433,900;100,-3783,900;200,-4017,900;33,-4050,900;-67,-4100,900;217,-3800,900;833,-3067,900;1084,-3483,900;900,-3500,900;-350,-1517,900;-2534,-1267,900;-2866,-1217,900;-2800,-683,900;-2617,283,900;350,-2800,900;817,-3350,900;866,-3050,900;784,-2567,900;550,-2967,900;-1900,-883,900;-2550,-183,900;-2550,333,900;-2684,67,900;-2316,-400,900;-4650,-400,1800;-300,-4650,900;-250,-3850,900;633,-3483,900;1267,-3317,900;-800,-1550,900;-2850,-200,900;-3117,-900,900;-3083,-1416,900;-3250,-1883,900;-3100,-2700,900;-2950,-3233,900;-3100,-2817,900;-3350,-2667,900;-1150,-3083,900;1400,-3150,900;2050,-3650,900;516,-2250,900;-200,-4000,900;50,-4133,900;100,-4183,900;134,-4017,900;2499,-3567,900;2684,-3850,900;633,-3150,900;-216,-3700,900;-550,-2817,900;-300,-3500,900;-100,-2683,900;-100,-3233,900;-67,-3267,900;-83,-3250,900;-300,-3300,900;-250,-3150,900;-200,-3100,900;-150,-3050,900;-67,-3050,900;1367,-3667,900;2566,-4450,900;3250,-4083,900;2283,-3400,900;851,-2400,900;300,-2750,900;883,-2866,900;800,-3100,900;1767,-2333,900;350,-3317,900;366,-3383,900;217,-2950,900;267,-2083,900;366,-3550,900;534,-3650,900;350,-3717,900;167,-3750,900;83,-3800,900;-250,-4150,900;-1050,-4200,900;-750,-4450,900;-750,-4200,900;-950,-4200,900;-1000,-4167,900;-850,-3733,900;0,-4100,900;-1250,-3867,900;-2467,-633,900;-1850,-4250,900;-1283,-6600,900;-5634,-5433,900;2584,-8167,900;5000,-8700,900;6200,-7133,900;2700,-7783,900;-1050,-10517,900;-1434,-10700,900;-2650,-10800,900;-1200,-8067,900;-2733,-7317,900;-4233,-8167,900;-4800,-8000,900;-3317,-7217,900;-3683,-6800,900;-3900,-6650,900;-3850,-6400,900;-3750,-5900,900;-3850,-6200,900;-3750,-5617,900;-3684,-5217,900;2534,-3433,900;4733,-3050,900;5083,-2817,900;4800,-3150,900;5334,-3217,900;4383,-1933,900;5317,-1617,900;6500,-2600,900;6483,-2800,900;7117,-3350,900;6583,-4417,900;6667,-4350,900;6900,-3700,900;7249,-3383,900;6901,-3350,900;6900,-3100,900;7250,-1933,900;7133,-433,900;7417,-150,900;2167,-5433,900;249,-8450,900;900,-9300,900;-933,-8783,900;-1450,-9017,900;-1650,-9050,900;-1233,-10033,900;-950,-9633,900;-350,-9233,900;-100,-9550,900;300,-9700,900;99,-9900,900;0,-9650,900;-299,-9450,900;-384,-9517,900;400,-10083,900;1134,-10033,900;1716,-9317,900;1984,-9550,900;2300,-9700,900;2333,-9567,900;4267,-5617,900;8000,333,900;7866,800,900;7434,1600,900;7916,1200,900;7834,650,900;8183,983,900;8350,1083,900;8533,583,900;9084,-200,900;8767,433,900;8599,383,900;9034,67,900;7300,1067,900;7433,1250,900;8667,1950,900;8950,2850,900;7950,2300,900;7850,1867,900;7466,1217,900;6700,1117,900;7217,2250,900;7150,3067,900;4033,5333,900;584,5434,900;-650,2166,900;0,833,900;1150,2267,900;800,2267,900;400,83,900;-34,0,900;17,0,5400;-17,0,900;17,-16,9900;-17,16,900;0,0,2700;17,0,900</track>
```

The whole file is available here:
https://pastebin.com/pyKZd1Dr

Comment: It looks like first two numbers are projected longitude and latitude, and the third is time stamp. Knowing where this point actually is would help in determining coordinate system. Time stamp converted gives 11/05/2011 14:00:00. Next three numbers are obviously offsets from the previous three, and so on.

Comment: @TomazicM I think you should make your comment into an answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo Since there was no response from the person asking and I couldn't find any projection that would sensibly match coordinates `[3832917,-49133]`, I think my comment is just a guess, not wort to be promoted to an answer.